# Migrating from Server 2003 R2 using IIS1 & FrontPage to Server 2012 using IIS8

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8, web-server

I'm attempting to migrate my site to a new server. I've already exported & imported the web site. Pages display properly, but when information is submitted from any page an error appears saying that the "_vti_bin directory cannot be found". After searching with Google I learned that this is cause by a lack of Front page technology.

What do I need to install to the new server to run the old front page forms?

Possibly helpful information: The directory doesn't exist on the website, but the forms work on the old server for some reason...(Still looking into why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like IIS8 doesn't support frontpage extensions.  There's [a third party vendor](http://www.rtr.com/fpse/Win2008R2/) that supplies them;  I haven't tried it myself.  But apparently,

> [As of December 18, 2010](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2011/07/frontpage-2002-server-extensions-for-iis-70-on-windows-server-2008-and-windows-vista), Microsoft FrontPage Server Extensions (FPSE)
>   2002 for Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 RTM is supported by
>   Ready-to-Run Software, Inc. For support and servicing, contact
>   Ready-to-Run Software, Inc .

and

> [The RTR FrontPage Server Extensions (RTR FPSE) for IIS 7.5 on Windows
>   Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 is available for immediate download from
>   Ready-to-Run Software.](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2011/07/rtr-frontpage-server-extensions-for-iis-75-on-windows-server-2008-r2-and-windows-7) The RTR FrontPage Server Extensions for IIS 7.5
>   on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 have the same functionality as
>   both the Microsoft FrontPage Server Extensions 2002 for IIS 7 on
>   Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista and the Microsoft FrontPage
>   Server Extensions 2002 for IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003. There is no
>   functional difference; the FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions have now
>   been ported to work with IIS 7.5 by RTR. As such, the basic install
>   prerequisites and procedures have not changed.

(Those are both from iis.net;  I don't work for them or anything.)

They do have [a version for 2012](http://www.rtr.com/fpse/Win2008R2/).

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft FrontPage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage) has long been depreciated along with its successor [Microsoft Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Web). Their functionality has been rolled into the Visual Studio product line starting with Visual Studio 2012.

In my experience these FrontPage-managed websites are almost always internal facing "Intranet" web pages without significant complexity and FrontPage is there just to provide an editing interface for the administrative staff to update content. If this is your use case, consider moving to a Wiki, Content Management System or *shudder* SharePoint.